# SFTP server pushing data to http backend

Tags: http, amazon-s3, https, backend, sftp

This is a bit of a strange requirement.
I need an SFTP server, which uses http endpoint as a back-end instead of file system.

[Apache mina](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/docs/sftp.md) is one possible candidate, sine it provides `SftpEventListener` with handler which has access to payload being transferred.

There are few other solutions, which has different storage backends. Http support is not out of the box for those.

proftpd and sftpplus also has hooks, which could be used to communicate with http endpoint, but still primary storage is a disk. Hopefully I'm looking for complete switch of the back-ends from disk->http.

Can you point me if such solutions exists, or a solution which can be customized.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sftp plus, Apache mina has the features i was after